# Texts overlaps image on resizing Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new with Bootstrap and css. Help out a newbie. When it is maximized, I have a layout that I want but when I re-size it to a smaller size, the texts overlaps the images on top of it. Your help is very much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<section id="work" class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1 class="text-center">My Work</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/portfolio3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/portfolio4.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">About Me</h2>
  <div class="col-text text-justify">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Web Designing </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body text-justify">
          <img src="images/webdesign.jpg" class="img-thumbnail center-block">
          <p class="lead text-center">
            Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Web Designing</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body text-justify">
          <img src="images/webdesign.jpg" class="img-thumbnail center-block">
          <p class="lead text-center">
            Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You want not to change the layout when in smaller screen?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to wrap each image in a bootstrap column so that they resize properly without interfering with each other.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg"  class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg"  class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/portfolio3.jpg"  class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/portfolio4.jpg"  class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg"  class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg"  class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear but, the images does not overlap each other. It's the next paragraph of texts that overlaps the images.

Comment: Oh kk. Just add some margin-bottom to the img container div